# Joomla-Development: Set default view

Tags: joomla-api, joomla-3.4, view, controller

I would like to set up a default view. If my component gets called by using `administrator/index.php?option=com_bestia&view=` I'm getting the error:

> 404 View not found [Name, Typ, Präfix]: bestia, html, bestiaView

com_banners does it better:
`administrator/index.php?option=com_banners&view=` results in showing the first page of banners component.

This is my controller:

```
class BestiaController extends JControllerLegacy 
{
    protected $default_view         =           'cpanel';

    /**
     * display function.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param bool $cachable (default: false)
     * @param bool $urlparams (default: false)
     * @return void
     */
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) 
    {
        require_once JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/bestia.php';

        $view       =   $this->input->get('view', 'cpanel');
        $layout     =   $this->input->get('layout', 'default');
        $id         =   $this->input->getInt('id');

        // Check for edit form.
        if ($layout == 'edit' && !$this->checkEditId('com_bestia.edit.'.$view, $id))
        {
            // Somehow the person just went to the form - we don't allow that.
            $this->setError(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_UNHELD_ID', $id));
            $this->setMessage($this->getError(), 'error');
            $this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_bestia&view='.$view.'s', false));

            return false;
        }

        parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your view files are missing or view class is named incorrectly (correct is [Prefix]View[Viewname]).

If I change the name of

```
administrator/components/com_banners/views/ to /viewx/
```

I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred.
500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: banners, html, bannersView
```

Switch it back to /views/ - and error goes away.